# Can anyone with access to the new "Matlab Coder" product show some output of the translation to C?

Tags: matlab

[Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) is a recently released MathWorks product. My understanding is that it is a Matlab-to-C compiler with the biggest advantage over previous solutions being that the resulting program does not need to be linked against a Matlab shared library.

Can someone with access to this product confirm the above? What are the dependencies of the translated programs and what kind of performance are we talking about? Also I would really like to see some example outputs, to know if the resulting C programs can be understood and improved without access to the Matlab source.

If done right this could be very powerful, allowing rapid prototyping in Matlab and instantaneous conversion to C when things are getting serious. I kind of whish it doesn't work well so that Python+Numpy+Scipy.weave is still superior ^^.

Comment: It would also be interesting if MATLAB would use some kind of BLAS acceleration in the translated code. Their web-demo looks a bit like they just convert matrix multiplication to simple loops.

Comment: You should also look at [Cython](http://cython.org) IMO its a lot better than Scipy.weave.

Comment: One thing I'd definitely be interested in too is its ability (or lack) to dynamically allocate memory. Some versions of the C translation utilities in the past have only allowed static allocations and this became a real issue when we needed to do production level C code generation with unknown inputs like files of non-predetermined length. +1 to the question: I'd like to hear other people's experience and maybe a survey of MatLab products surrounding code generation.

Comment: @Paul Yes Cython looks very good for optimizing Python code. But I am working in Computer Vision where performance is critical and the final code usually has to be C/C++. I use Python for rapid prototyping, and scipy.weave allows me to port my program one function at a time. PyCUDA allows the same workflow for parallelizing computations using CUDA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MATLAB Coder can allocate memory using malloc, so you can generate C code from MATLAB functions that operate on dynamically sized data. You can also choose the option of static allocation with a maximum size for variables.

RE: using BLAS for matrix multiplication – while the generated C code doesn’t automatically include any processor/platform specific optimizations, there is a feature called Target Function Library, which that allows users to write their own implementation of primitive operations (such as matrix multiplication), and include them in the generated code. You can hook up BLAS libraries to MATLAB Coder via that method. There’s also an ability to include optimized processor specific calls for larger functions through custom code integration and conditional compilation that lets you specify one set of code to use for code generation, and another set for simulation (for example, an optimized FIR function for an Texas Instruments DSP and functionally equivalent code for simulation that can execute on your PC written in C or in MATLAB).

Hope this is helpful -- 
Arvind Ananthan; Product Manager for MATLAB Coder; MathWorks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I guess you know what you are talking about! I didn't know about the Target Function Library feature. It seems to add a lot of value to Matlab Coder.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Matlab Coder with Real Time Workshop (RTW) in order to generate self standind standard C code.

First of all you are asked to use a Matlab subset called "Embedded Matlab" you can find the doc about it on the web

You also have to avoid any dynamic exploitation of variables and you can't obviously generate c code for plots or figures.

The code it generates could be a mess to understand but it works. 
you should actually not try to understand it. In a certain way it is as you would try to understand the assembler your compiler generates from a C code you wrote, quite pointless.

another thing you should take care of is to declare persistent big data types (vectors, big arryes, etc.) otherwise they will be allocated into your stack...

good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I feel like it is something like Cython for Matlab. Would it be possible to post an example of a very basic program source and generated code? Is the generated code fast (compared to BLAS-optimized C code for example)?